Overflow difference between Chrome and Firefox browsers
I have this project I've been working on as part of a roadmap to web development, and I developed this sidebar that has an inner scrolling list. In Chrome, the inner list scrolls, but in Firefox, each of its children scrolls independently. The code, without extra bits is the following:
See Codepen: https://codepen.io/rins6618/pen/yLmJxRy (I cannot seem to get snippets).
<nav class="flex" id="sidebar">
  <header>
    <button id="project-selector" class="flex">
      <div id="project-icon" class="flex">B</div>
      <div id="project-name" class="flex">Blank Project</div>
    </button>
    </div>
    <iconify-icon icon="material-symbols:side-navigation" style=" font-size: 2rem;" class="toggle-btn"></iconify-icon>
  </header>
  <div class="flex" id="scrollable-sidebar">
    <ul class="flex listing">
      <li>
        <h3> Projects</h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button class="flex">
          <span class="flex">Create new project...</span>
        </button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button class="flex">
          <span class="flex">Delete a project...</span>
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="flex listing">
      <li>
        <h3>This project</h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button class="flex">
          <span class="flex">Rename this project...</span>
        </button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button class="flex">
          <span class="flex">View notes...</span>
        </button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button class="flex">
          <span class="flex">View due dates...</span>
        </button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button class="flex">
          <span class="flex">Change project color...</span>
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <ul class="flex listing">
      <li>
        <button class="flex">
          <span class="flex">About</span>
        </button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button class="flex">
          <span class="flex">Settings</span>
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</nav>

CSS:
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

:root {
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #efefef;
}

main {
    margin-left: 30rem;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

#sidebar {
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0.5rem 0.5rem 0 0;
    width: 30rem;
    height: 100dvh;
    padding: 1rem;

    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;

    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;

    border-radius: 0rem 1rem 0rem 0rem;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 0px 3px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0px 3px 6px;
}           

#scrollable-sidebar {
    flex: 1;
    border-top: 0.25rem solid #eee;
    border-bottom: 0.25rem solid #eee;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

#scrollable-sidebar > * {
    padding: 0 1rem;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: visible;
}

#scrollable-sidebar > *:first-child {
    border-top: none;
}

#scrollable-sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

#sidebar header {
    transition: background-color .3s;
    height: 5rem;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
}

#sidebar:first-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
}

#project-selector {
    z-index: 3;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: inherit;
    transition: background-color .1s;
    transition: box-shadow .05s;
    position: relative;
    padding: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 1ch;
    width: 75%;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    box-shadow: none;
}

#project-selector > * {
    pointer-events: none;
}

#project-selector:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
}

#project-icon {
    margin-right: 1ch;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background: rgb(163,163,163);
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(163,163,163,1) 0%, rgba(58,58,58,1) 100%);
    border-radius: 5%;
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
    width: 2rem;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #fff;
}

#project-name {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    max-width: 18ch;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


#scrollable-sidebar ul {
    min-height: fit-content;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 1rem;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 1rem;
    gap: 1rem;
}

#sidebar li > h3 {
    padding: 0.5rem 0 1rem 0;
    user-select: none;
}

#sidebar li > button {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    transition: color .3s;
    transition: background-color .3s;
    color: #444;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0.75rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    gap: 2ch;
}

#sidebar li > button:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #000;
}

#sidebar li > button > span {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#sidebar > footer > ul {
    margin: 0 1rem;
    min-height: fit-content;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 1rem;
}

I know I can solve this by having one <ul> element. This is not the point. I want to know the why behind the fact that Chrome and Firefox are different on such a basic rule. What if I had to keep two elements from scrolling and I had no other choice? Keep in mind the CSS rules make sure the <ul> shouldn't be scrollable, yet Firefox still makes them scrollable. (relevant CSS rule below);
#scrollable-sidebar > * {
    padding: 0 1rem;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: visible;
}

Differences:
Chrome

Firefox

There was a question involving sidebars in StackOverflow, but not pertinent to what I am having trouble with.

Your HTML is invalid. A <div> cannot be a child of <button>

Putting your code through a validator can help e.g. https://validator.w3.org/

The difference appears to be that Firefox is not respecting min-height: fit-content correctly. In Chrome, the ul's height is set to that of its content, so there's no overflow and no need for scrollbars. In Firefox, the ul's height is shrunk by the default flex-shrink:1, so the ul's are shorter than their content, the content overflows and Firefox accordingly shows the scrollbars.
Also with
#scrollable-sidebar > * {
    padding: 0 1rem;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: visible;
}

overflow-x: hidden; and overflow-y: visible; don't mix. Consequently the overflow-y: visible;is automatically converted to overflow-y: auto;
A couple of ways forward. One is to add
#scrollable-sidebar ul {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

so that the ul's aren't shrunk and their content doesn't overflow.
Another is to change the overflow rules to
#scrollable-sidebar > * {
    padding: 0 1rem;
    overflow-x: clip; /* i.e. use clip, not hidden */
    overflow-y: visible;
}

so the ul's are not scroll containers.

And his HTML is invalid.

I see. Strange that it had flex-shrink set to 1, but I'm very thankful to you for telling me overflow values can't be mixed by whatever combination. I just assumed that was the case, but it does make sense that visible and hidden overflow shouldn't mix together.

Regarding the invalid HTML, I also didn't know about the inline validation from buttons. I just used buttons as semantic structuring. I'm probably going to replace it for another div, because on second thought a button element isn't that semantically connected to a dropdown menu as I first thought.
